# Que requiere spring para poder usar retrofit con mi api Rest spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, spring, retrofit

Tengo una api rest con spring boot con un login de usuarios pero no consigo que mi retrofit funcione y creo que es porque me faltan configuraciones de la api
Esta es mi clase de webSecurityConfig he leido algo de authInterceptor o algo asi no necesito ni encriptar ni nada solo poder hacer login con retrofit ya que asi siempre que intento hacer login hace como que entra al login pero pongas lo que pongas dice que esta mal

````
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class DatabaseWebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select email, password, status from students where email=? ")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("SELECT s.email, p.perfil FROM students s " +
                        "INNER JOIN perfil p ON p.id = s.PERFIL_ID "+
                        "WHERE s.email = ?");


    }


    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }


    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}```

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda, gracias
````